# How to use the Java MP3 ID3 Tag Library to retrieve album artwork

Tags: java, id3v2

I'm making an mp3 player. I'm using the  [Java mp3 id3 tag library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javamusictag/?source=dlp). I understand that album artwork is encoded as a ID3v2 tag.

I can access the ID3v2 tag of a mp3 file however I cannot get the artwork!
None of the methods in the AbstractID3v2 class, in the 
 [API](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) seem to retrieve a picture.

How does one use this library?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up using another library, I used [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)

It's a great library which is easy to use. Here's sample code I used to get the album artwork

```
Mp3File song = new Mp3File(filename);
if (song.hasId3v2Tag()){
     ID3v2 id3v2tag = song.getId3v2Tag();
     byte[] imageData = id3v2tag.getAlbumImage();
     //converting the bytes to an image
     BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));
}
```

Comment: I am unable to import that library. I tried both `id3-1.6.0d9.jar` and `jid3lib-0.5.4.jar`, but neither has `Mp3File`.

Comment: Does it work for other audio file formats too? Or need to find those as well? Do other audio file formats even have something similar to this?

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) which can read/write Mp3, Mp4 (Mp4 audio, M4a and M4p audio) Ogg Vorbis, Flac and Wma + some others (album art too).

```
MP3File f = (Mp3File)AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
List<Artwork> artworkList;
if (f.hasID3v1Tag()) {
    ID3v1Tag v1tag = f.getID3v1Tag();
    artworkList = (List<Artwork>) v1tag.getArtworkList();
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I think that library is broken. I get: `Could not find class 'sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer', referenced from method org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.readV2Tag`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using mp3agic and this is another way!

Get Jar here: https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.mpatric/mp3agic/0.9.0/source-code

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
if (mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
   ID3v2 id3v2Tag = mp3file.getId3v2Tag();
   byte[] imageData = id3v2Tag.getAlbumImage();
}

if (imageData != null) {
   String mimeType = id3v2Tag.getAlbumImageMimeType();
   RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("album-artwork", "rw");
   file.write(data);
   file.close();
}
```