# Edited ID3 tags not showing in windows explorer

Tags: java, api, mp3, id3

I am working on a program that looks at an mp3 file and checks if it has it's ID3 data. If some data is missing it will query EchoNest (music database) for more data.

My problems is that when I update the ID3 tags Windows Explorer doesn't seem to recognize it (ie when the files are in the "Details" view the Artist, Title, Album columns are blank).
When I run my program a second time on the file my program finds the metadata just like it would find in a file that has all of it's data at first.

I am using the ID3 tag library found here:
http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

Is there something I am missing?

```
public void writeData(boolean pForce)
{
    if (mIsUpdated || pForce)
    {
         try 
         {
             File file = new File(mPath);
             RandomAccessFile destFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
             ID3v1 tag = new ID3v1();
             tag.setAlbum(mAlbum);
             tag.setArtist(mArtist);
             tag.setTitle(mTitle);
             tag.write(destFile);
         } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
         {
             System.out.println("No File Found At " + mPath);
         } 
         catch (IOException ex) 
         { 
             System.out.println("Error when writting to file: " + mPath);
         }
     }         
}
```

Just as a not I know that there are programs out there that do this same thing but I'm looking to add this as a function of my program. It's not so much about the functionality as it is about the learning how to make a program that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ID3v2 tags, because when I was **reading** tags (with that library) from music files in windows, only v2 seemed to work. Hope it helps

EDIT:
If that doesn't work, I found this on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728621/how-to-use-the-java-mp3-id3-tag-library-to-retrieve-album-artwork) using [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic): (the image stuff is to do with album artwork)

```
Mp3File song = new Mp3File(filename);
if (song.hasId3v2Tag()){
   ID3v2 id3v2tag = song.getId3v2Tag();
   byte[] imageData = id3v2tag.getAlbumImage();
   //converting the bytes to an image
   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));
}
```